# Android: Change number with a gesture

Tags: android, numbers, textfield, gesture

I am trying to change a number in my app, by draggin on top of my EditText field.

Example.

I have number 5 in the middle of the field. If I drag from the middle to the right side, the number inside the field should change from 5 to 6,7,8,9 etc, and if I drag to the left it should change to 4,3,2,1, etc. I should change in one drag, so the further you drag, the more the number changes.

I'm thinking it could be accomplished with Detection Common Gestures in Android, together with a GestureOverlay on top of the field.

I know how to handle basic gesture, but I dont know how to "calculate" the number, from the distance the user is dragging.

Anyone got any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Save the start position.  As they drag, get the current position.  Find the difference between the two, this is the amount moved.  Divide by some constant (which should probably be based on the screen's x resolution) to figure out how big the change is.

Comment: Thanks Gabe. Can you make that an answer instead, so I can mark your suggestion as the result ?